# Problem with extracting a .tar.gz file

Tags: tar, archive, extract

I've downloaded a '.tar.gz' file from [here](http://www.scilab.org/download/5.4.1/scilab-5.4.1.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz). File size is 152 MB.

The downloaded file size is 450 MB on my computer !!

I tried to extract that file but I get below error :

> gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data
>
> format violated tar: Unexpected
>
> EOF in archive tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: That message mean that the archive file is broken. You should try to redownload it

Comment: Is there any way to repair a broken file ?

Comment: @HamedKamrava - not really... how would you know if the repair has fixed what was broken?  Best to re-download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser probably un-gzipped it automatically, leaving an uncompressed file in plain tar format rather than tar.gz; when I do this for that archive manually using gunzip, I get a file of about 468 MB. Try untarring it without the 'z' decompression flag:

```
tar xf scilab-5.4.1.bin.linux-i686.tar.gz
```

or, depending on the file name:

```
tar xf scilab-5.4.1.bin.linux-i686.tar
```